# Appending To Files Challenge

Tags: python, file, text

I write a program to append the times table for our poem in sample.txt
So , this is all of my code

```
    numbers = 1
for i in range(2, 12):
    while 13 >= numbers > 0:
        multiply = numbers * i
        print('| {0} Times {1} is {2} '.format(numbers, i, multiply))
        numbers += 1
print('=' * 21)

with open('times_table.txt', 'w') as times:
    for table in times:
        print(table, file=times)
```

and the output is:

```
| 1 Times 2 is 2 
| 2 Times 2 is 4 
| 3 Times 2 is 6 
| 4 Times 2 is 8 
| 5 Times 2 is 10 
| 6 Times 2 is 12 
| 7 Times 2 is 14 
| 8 Times 2 is 16 
| 9 Times 2 is 18 
| 10 Times 2 is 20 
| 11 Times 2 is 22 
| 12 Times 2 is 24 
| 13 Times 2 is 26 
========================================
```

But because of code at the end lines for files appending , I'm facing this error below :
for table in times:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

So , finally I don't know how to append this time table stuffs into a sample.txt file .
I really appreciate you all guys . If you can possibly help me with this .

Comment: You're opening the file for _writing_, and then trying to _read_ from it.

Comment: The file writing should happen in the same loop that prints to the screen.  Why is it in a separate loop at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to the file, you should use `'a'` instead of `'w'` ! you can  write these contents on file directly.

```
numbers = 1
with open('times_table.txt', 'a') as file:
    for i in range(2, 12):
        while 13 >= numbers > 0:
            multiply = numbers * i
            file.write(f'| {numbers} Times {i} is {multiply}\n')
            numbers += 1
    file.write('=' * 21)
```

Comment: He's using the `file=times` argument to the print call, so he is also writing to the file.  Opening it just for reading won't work either.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've edited my answer, i hope he means the same.